# .js could not be found in my Visual Studio even if it is there already

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap-select css and js in my Web-form project and I imported it in the header section of my aspx but this error/warning occurs

[image]

Comment: What's your root directory ? Try putting a `/` before `scripts`.

Comment: This could happen when the master and content pages are in different folders. @noob's suggestion should solve the issue for you.

Comment: You are linking a **CSS file** but the url says **"Scripts/..."**. Scripts folder usually contain JS files and not CSS files. Can you confirm this ?